# Time Scheduling in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the List of the requested user and I want to upload the list of the user every day at 7 pm on each day. how can i do that using Spring Boot.And yes, it should also check whether the list is available or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with `@Scheduled` annotation in one of your methods of the bean. In order to enable scheduling you need to put `@EnableScheduling` annotation in one of your config classes, can be the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class TestingApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestingApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then you create a class, annotate it with `@Component` and create a method with `@Scheduled` annotation with a cron statement inside:

```
@Component
public class MyWorkerComponent {

    @Autowired
    private MyListChecker myListChecker;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 19 * * ?")
    public void doTheListThingy() {
        if (myListChecker.isTheListAvailable()) {
            // your task logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried using your solution it really worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

First,you should make a descition when your application have more than one instance the task need to executed once or can executed more than once.

If the task can executed more than once,the method provided by @Pijotrek and @mkjh is good. If the task must executed only once you must use `Quartz Scheduler` or other framework support distribute  scheduling task sysytem.more information you can get from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-quartz)